# Clear list of "Unavailable Migrations" (Symfony 3)

Tags: php, symfony

There are some migrations, that was deleted, and left at the list of "Unavailable Migrations". How can I clear it, because every time notice message annoy a little bit. My guess is

`migrations:doctrine:version`

[image: console]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Whenever the bundle reports executed unavailable migrations it means that there are migration identifiers in the `migrations_versions` database table from when you previously ran it.

To get rid of the notification, make sure that when you delete a migration file, delete its corresponding identifier from the database table.

You can do this with (or manually):

`php bin/console doctrine:migrations:version YYYYMMDDHHMMSS --delete`

Or, rewind the migration with:

`php bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute YYYYMMDDHHMMSS --down`

*but this will run the down function of that migration file undoing whatever it set* and remove it from the database.

Answer (score 13):

I have tried

```
php bin/console doctrine migrations:version YYYYMMDDHHMMSS --delete
```

and

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute YYYYMMDDHHMMSS --down
```

but it works only if we actually have migration.

[image]

I asked about situation when migration is deleted. But thanks DevDonkey for information about **migration_versions** table.

My solution is, to run

`php bin/console doctrine:migrations:status --show-versions`

and see 
[image]

And delete from **migration_versions** these rows.

Comment: which is exactly what I said to do.

Comment: The `--show-versions` option appears to have been removed in Doctrine Migrations 3.0

Comment: after `--show-versions` was removed, you can get a similar view by running `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:list`

Answer (score 1):

Once you deleted them, you can simply :

> DELETE FROM doctrine_migration_versions;